# Installing pygame for python 3.x, getting difficulties

Tags: python, pygame

I have just installed the latest version of python, 3.4.3 32 bit and the corresponding pygame.  I get this error when importing pygame

```
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Please help fix the error

Comment: Seems like pygame isn't installed, are you certain it's the version for python3? where did you download pygame from?

Comment: I used this site http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uninstalling Python 3.4 and installing Python 3.2, then reinstall the 3.2 version of pygame. I could not see a python 3.4 version of pygame when I looked on the pygame website and unless you specifically need the features of 3.4 pygame for Python 3.2 should work fine.